# How do I make VS Code Bracket Colorizer work everywhere?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I changed the colors of the bracket pair colorizer to shades of gray. But it only works in only one folder of my entire Ubuntu WSL. In every other directory I open, the syntax highlighter brings back the rainbow colors.

How do I make this work everywhere as I intended it?

Here's my settings.json:

```
"bracketPairColorizer.colorMode": "Independent",
"bracketPairColorizer.independentPairColors": [
    [
        "()",
        [
            "#555"
        ],
        "Yellow"
    ],
    [
        "[]",
        [
            "#555",
            "#777",
            "#999",
            "#bbb"
        ],
        "Blue"
    ],
    [
        "{}",
        [
            "#555",
            "#777",
            "#999",
            "#bbb"
        ],
        "Red"
    ]
],
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": null,
```

Answer (score 1):

Bracket Matching or Bracket Colorizer is now the native feature in VSCode.

1. Open `settings.json` in vs code
2. Paste the following code inside the `json` file

```json
{
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "editor.guides.bracketPairs":"active"
}
```

Source : [Bracket Pair](https://github.com/CoenraadS/BracketPair#readme)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have saved the settings as workspace settings rather than user settings. To make sure your settings changes are global to all projects (user settings) ensure you are editing the settings.json file in one of the following locations (depending on your main os).

```
- Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
- macOS $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
- Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

Comment: Thanks. But that's exactly where my settings.json it. It still doesn't solve it.